# error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

The code below don't compile in vs 2012. In line 4 I got an error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'. Can somebody help me to fix it. I would be very appreciate.

ps. dont' focus on case insensitive, i have delete something to make the code simpler.

```
#include<functional>

template<typename Ty>
struct case_insensitive_less : public binary_function<Ty, Ty, bool>{
    bool operator()(Ty const& left, Ty const& right) const
    {
        return (left < right);
    }
};

int main(){}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `std` namespace:

```
std::binary_function
```

Note that [std::binary_function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function) is deprecated in C++11. If you have C++11 support, consider using [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and/or [lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B).

Comment: So it's deprecated, got it. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mike - deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work. Just that in the future it **might** be removed. So far, nothing that's been deprecated in any C++ standard has been removed.